# How to add the javafx plugin in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, efxclipse

I have added javafx plugin to eclipse, three months back but now i cant add the plugin in eclipse. I have used the below link:
e(fx)clipse = http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/0.9.0/site
Xtext = http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/

And also i searched many but i cant install it. 
Could some one help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javafx - http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/0.9.0/site ... this is working for me. kepler version 4.3

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

In the install wizard, enter the site for e(fx)clipse you have in the question. Expand the "e(fx)clipse - single components" node and select "Basic", "CSS", and "FXML". Obviously there are some features there I didn't install but this seemed to work for everything I need.

Comment: yes it worked for me too but not now... i installed the plugins on another system before 2 months but now i having issue.. Can you please install now and let me know.

Comment: I had worked for me whit this link  http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/0.9.0/site and selecting Basic,CSS and XML

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Xtext-Feature in the release repo is too high already - you need to have Xtext 2.5.1 - as an alternate use the all in one download from http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html

Comment: i have installed xtext successfully but i cant install the first link plugins on my pc.